# Parse: Do users created with 'enableAutomaticUser' get discarded every time the app is terminated?

Tags: parse-platform, pfuser

Parse version 1.7.1 as built by Cocoapods

I have a completely bare project where I set up an anonymous user through `[PFUser enableAutomaticuser]`. Judging by the `_Users` table in Parse, it looks like the ID's are discarded when I terminate the app, and regenerated on the subsequent app launch. 
At no point do I log out or do anything that should nil out the user.

Is this the intended behavior or a bug?

My code, if it matters:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{   
    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId(APP_ID,
        clientKey: CLIENT_KEY)

    // Create or authenticate anonymous user
    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveEventually { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success)
        {   
             // Setup push notifications
        }
    }

    // Track statistics around application opens.
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    return true
}
```

If it helps...
Looks like the user exists at the last moment of the app's lifetime in `applicationWillTerminate:`, but it is nil in the next launch's `applicationDidFinishLauchingWithOptions:` before the call to enable the automatic user.